# UWP C# Windows 10 IoT datepicker & timepicker to update system date & time

Tags: c#, datepicker, uwp, timepicker, windows-10-iot-core

I would like to know if there is any method to update/change system date & time using datepicker & timepicker? I can't find any sample code on it for reference. Please advise.
Thanks.

updated:

[image: I encountered exception when setting the date.]
Is there anything that I missed out?

[image: System Management Capabilities]

Comment: A UWP app is not allowed to change the time on the user's device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[DateTimeSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.datetimesettings)* is included in Windows IoT Extension SDK 16299.The method ***SetSystemDateTime*** is used to set the system date and time.Please refer to below codes.

```
    //Change Date by DatePicker
    private void DatePickerChangeSetting_DateChanged(object sender, DatePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTimeSettings.SetSystemDateTime(e.NewDate.UtcDateTime);
    }

    //Change Time by TimePicker
    private void tpChangeSetting_TimeChanged(object sender, TimePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

        var newDateTime = new DateTime(currentDate.Year,
                                       currentDate.Month, 
                                       currentDate.Day, 
                                       e.NewTime.Hours, 
                                       e.NewTime.Minutes, 
                                       e.NewTime.Seconds);

        DateTimeSettings.SetSystemDateTime(newDateTime);
    }
```

@Naikrovek, in the document linked, it is not error about the parameter *DateTime/DateTimeOffset*.In essence, the two can be transformed into each other.Please see [Converting between DateTime and DateTimeOffsetc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset).In addition, the issue you mentioned about displaying the updated time on 16299 has been fixed, *[IoTCoreDefaultApp](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/IoTCoreDefaultApp)* changed to with call NativeTimeMethods.GetLocalTime method.

In addition,i posted my reference setting and appxmanifest capability setting,you can install Windows IoT Extension for the UWP from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)(download the windows 10 sdk and then install).
[image]
[image]

Comment: hi Micheal.. I seem to encounter an exception (UnauthorizedAccessException) when setting the date & time. I have uploaded a screenshot of it. Can you please advise?

Comment: You need to add the 'System Management' capability to your Package.appxmanifest.It allows apps to have basic system administration privileges.

Comment: Hi Micheal, I have added system management capabilities prior. I have attached a printscreen.

Comment: What version is your Windows IoT Core?I have tested the code on 16299.64, it works.

Comment: I am using windowsIoT, version=10.0.16299.0 ..I dont see any latest update available.

Comment: You can update the system with [Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/deviceportal)(***Windows Update->Check for updates***),or re-flash the image to your SD card with [IoT Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/iotdashboard).

Comment: Hi Micheal, I am also running debug on local machine.. any way to have the same update for my VS2017? my local machine - laptop shows 10.0.16299 build 16299.

Comment: Hi Micheal, I am also running debug on local machine. Will there be any issue with the setup?

Comment: Hi,mylim.It can only run on Windows IoT Core.The method is in Windows IoT Extension SDK (introduced v10.0.16299.0).

Comment: Hi Micheal, can you advise on your reference setup at your end so I could setup according to yours. Thank you.

Comment: @mylim, I have posted the reference in my reply. Please note, DateTimeSettings can only available for Window IoT Core 16299 or newer.

Comment: confirmed. after 4 months. this works and my rtc module seems malfunctined. I totally removed this module and now changing manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the IoT UWP extensions referenced by your project, and you have the System Management capability added to your appxmanifest, you can set the Date and Time [via this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.datetimesettings).

The documentation linked seems ambiguous to me; it mixes mentions of use of an offset versus the actual date and time.  I suspect copy paste errors, and I am not sure if this method will actually do what you need.

Note that the default home application on IoT Core 16299 has a bug that will not always display the updated time, so don't rely on that screen to know if your clock is correct until this bug is fixed.